# I cannot add a product to cart when I click the button using javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

When I try clicking on the add to cart button, it won't add to my cart. I don't know how to fix this. Is the code missing something important? I want it so that when I click on "add to cart" a product will be added so that it will appear in the shopping cart as an item added.

**View and Javascript codes for the cart**

```
@model  PagedList.IPagedList<E_Game.ViewModel.ShopVM>
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc





<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>User Page</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/user.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">


        <div style=" text-align:center; font-family:Arial; margin-left:177px; margin-top:-10px;font-size:20px;">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div style="float: right; background-color: #fff; float: left; width: 100%; color: #1a1a1a;" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-100px;font-size:50px; font-family:Verdana"> SAVAGE GAME</p>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                @if (Session["CartCounter"] == null)
                {
    @Html.ActionLink("Cart", "ShoppingCart", "User", new { id = "cartItem" }) }
                else
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cart(" + Session["CartCounter"] + ")", "ShoppingCart", "User", new { id = "cartItem" });
                }
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="sidebar-container">
            <div style="text-align:center;" class="sidebar-logo">

                <img style="margin-left:-20px;height:70px; width:200px" src="~/Images/konsol.jpg" />
            </div>
            <ul class="sidebar-navigation">
                <li class="header">Navigation</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Homepage
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> About
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header">Shopping</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Categories
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Products
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header">Settings</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> User
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Log Out
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="content-container">

            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="olContent f1"><h2 style="color:black">Search Product/Category</h2></div>
            <div class="olSearch fr">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keyword" name="searchKey" class="inputComn houseText form-control" />
                <div class="searchIcon">
                    <button type="button" class="searchBtn">
                        <img src="~/Images/searchIcon.png" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
                <div style="background-color:white; " class="jumbotron">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid black; margin:15px; width:200px;">
            <div style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px dashed solid; ">
                <h4> @item.ProductName</h4>
            </div>
            <div>


                <div class="col-md-10" style=" margin-left:-10px">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" width="150" height="250" />
                    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
                        <a style=" margin-left:35px">@item.Price.ToString("#,## $")</a>
                        <br />
                        <a style="margin-left:35px;">@Html.ActionLink("Description", "Description", "Shop")</a>
                        <br />


                        <div style="float:left; font-size:7px; color:#65a0c9;">

                       //add to cart button
                       <button type="button" name="AddToCart" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-primary" itemid="@item.ProductId" id="btnAddToCart" onclick="AddToCart(this)">Add To Cart</button>

                          
                            
                        </div>





                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>}
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div style="float:left;  margin-top:450px; margin-left:-650px; ">
                        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>



</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddtoCart(item) {
        var ProductId = $(item).attr("itemid");
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ProductId", itemid);
        $.ajax(
            {
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
              url: '/User/Index',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        $("#CartProduct").text("Cart(" + data.Counter + ")");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("We can not added your product.");
                }
            });
    }


</script>
```

My controller for creating adding to the cart event and index

```
using E_Game.Models;
using E_Game.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList.Mvc;
using PagedList;
using E_Game.Repository;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace E_Game.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: User
        // GET: Shop
        GameSalesSystemEntities db = new GameSalesSystemEntities();

        private GameSalesSystemEntities objgameSalesSystemEntities;
        List<ShoppingCartModel> listofShoppingCartModels;
        public UserController()
        {
            objgameSalesSystemEntities = new GameSalesSystemEntities();
            listofShoppingCartModels = new List<ShoppingCartModel>();

        }

        public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
        {

            IEnumerable<ShopVM> listOfShopVMs = (from objProduct in objgameSalesSystemEntities.Products
                                                 join objCategory in objgameSalesSystemEntities.Categories
                                                 on objProduct.CategoryId equals objCategory.CategoryId
                                                 select new ShopVM()
                                                 {
                                                     Image = objProduct.Image,
                                                     ProductName = objProduct.ProductName,
                                                     PDescription = objProduct.PDescription,
                                                     Price = objProduct.Price,
                                                     ProductId = objProduct.ProductId,
                                                     Category = objCategory.CategoryName,

                                                     ProductCode = objProduct.ProductCode


                                                 }).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 8);
            return View(listOfShopVMs);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(string ProductId)
        {

            ShoppingCartModel objShoppingCartModel = new ShoppingCartModel();
            Products objProduct = objgameSalesSystemEntities.Products.Single(model => model.ProductId.ToString() == ProductId);

            if (Session["CartCounter"] != null)
            {
                listofShoppingCartModels = Session["CartProduct"] as List<ShoppingCartModel>;
            }
            if (listofShoppingCartModels.Any(model => model.ProductId == ProductId))
            {
                objShoppingCartModel = listofShoppingCartModels.Single(model => model.ProductId == ProductId);
                objShoppingCartModel.Quantity = objShoppingCartModel.Quantity + 1;
                objShoppingCartModel.Total = objShoppingCartModel.Quantity * objShoppingCartModel.UnitPrice;
            }
            else
            {
                objShoppingCartModel.ProductId = ProductId;
                objShoppingCartModel.Image = objProduct.Image;
                objShoppingCartModel.ProductName = objProduct.ProductName;
                objShoppingCartModel.Quantity = 1;
                objShoppingCartModel.UnitPrice = objProduct.Price;
                objShoppingCartModel.Total = objProduct.Price;
                listofShoppingCartModels.Add(objShoppingCartModel);


            }
            Session["CartCounter"] = listofShoppingCartModels.Count;
            Session["CartProduct"] = listofShoppingCartModels;
            return Json(new { Success = true, Counter = listofShoppingCartModels.Count }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
        {
            listofShoppingCartModels = Session["CartProduct"] as List<ShoppingCartModel>;
            return View(listofShoppingCartModels);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your JavaScript code.

Firstly, you are setting the button's onclick attribute to `AddToCart(this)`, but in your JavaScript code, the function is called `AddtoCart` (with a lowercase t).

Secondly, you have created a variable called `ProductId` in the line:

`var ProductId = $(item).attr("itemid");`

but are instead referencing a variable called `itemid` (which doesn't exist) later on:

`formData.append("ProductId", itemid);`